Conflicts when merging after rebasing in a working branch
I have a feature branch derived from master which is some months old now. I want the latest commits from master in my feature branch so I am rebasing.
However, I am doing this in a new working branch, derived from my feature branch. The rebase has been performed in this branch so it can be reviewed in a PR before it is merged.
The problem is that all of the conflicts resolved in the rebase are now showing as conflicts in Bitbucket which is preventing me from merging the rebase to the feature branch.
I assume this is because the rebase has made new commits which conflict with the old ones. Is there a way to fix this so I can merge?
Rebasing again to the feature branch doesn't seem right, it'll overwrite the master commits. Squashing isn't an option as I want to keep the commit history. What else can be done?

First rebasing and then merging the rebased branch into the original branch does not seem to make sense to me. Why don't you just rebase the feature branch onto master, or just merge master into the feature branch?

Continuing with @mkrieger1's comment, or, if you already have a branch called new-working-branch which is rebased onto master with conflicts resolved, then create a PR from that branch into master and do the code review there. (Don't PR new-working-branch into original-feature-branch. The original feature branch can probably just be deleted now, or at least saved until you complete the PR.)

The reason is so that a pull request can be created on bitbucket for other engineers to review and approve before the changes go into the branch.

Right- that's what a PR is generally for. I'm pointing out that you've already fixed up your old feature branch by creating a new and improved version of that feature branch. So set up the new version to be PR'd into its final destination. (I assume master) and do the code review on that PR. Your old branch is no longer needed (except maybe for comparison if you think your new version might have a mistake in conflict resolution.)

@TTT Ideally, we'd be able to continue with the existing feature branch. Is there no reasonable way to resolve these conflicts?

If you want to use the original feature branch, then you can. That's what @mkrieger1's comment is suggesting. Use the original feature to do the rebase or merge.

Oh... maybe I misunderstood the actual problem. Do you already have a PR setup with the original feature branch? If yes, and you wish to retain the history of that PR, then what you could do is a hard reset of the old feature branch to point to the new and improved feature branch. Then you would need to force push that original feature branch, and it (I assume) would update the PR with the new version, but retain the PR history because the branch name didn't change. (I've not used BitBucket but this is how other tools work.)

Side note, when you ask "Is there no reasonable way to resolve these conflicts?" I think you're referring to the conflicts that occur when you try to merge the new-feature-branch into old-feature-branch. So the answer to that question is: No, there is no reasonable way to resolve those conflicts because it's not even reasonable to merge the new version of the branch into the old version of the branch. That would just leave you with duplicated commits and a confusing history. If your new branch is how you want it, you could also delete your old one and rename the new one to the old name.
